# Chat implementation in windows form using SignalR

Tags: windows, signalr

I am trying to implement chat application in windows form using SignalR. Actually I had created the web chat application using signalR now i want to synchronize it with windows application.
I am facing following problems

1) How to initialize the hub class as in web application we initialize it in javascript on page load. So how can we innitialize the hub and in web application there is global file to maphub for dynamically generating the signalr javascript so where in windows application can i map the hub to dynamically generate the same.

2) As i want to synchronize the windows application with the web application so do i need to keep both the projects under one solution or can i synchronize the two different solutions??

Please provide the startup code for the first problem as i have searched alot but not getting any way to implement the chat in windows form. the code i found on net just raising errors but helping me in any sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a full working sample for using [SignalR in WinForms and WPF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b)

You can download it and play with it.

There is a WinForms Server and Client which can be your starting point.

It is a good idea to keep the projects under one solution, but its up to you. The WinForms projects will need a server URL where they can communicate with each other (you can see this in the sample code from the above link)

Comment: hi Umair  Link you refernced is not working. can you please give the code on this page only.

Comment: That page does not exist

Comment: I have fixed the link now. Sorry but I think the link was changed.